# LNK2019 Error when calling methods of a static member in .cpp file

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I am getting these errors in my code, they are all related to one static member in my Game class.

```
Game.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::shared_ptr<class MainMenuScene> __thiscall SceneManager::AddScene<class MainMenuScene>(void)" (??$AddScene@VMainMenuScene@@@SceneManager@@QAE?AV?$shared_ptr@VMainMenuScene@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Game::init(char const *,int,int,bool)" (?init@Game@@QAEXPBDHH_N@Z)
Game.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::shared_ptr<class GameSelectScene> __thiscall SceneManager::AddScene<class GameSelectScene>(void)" (??$AddScene@VGameSelectScene@@@SceneManager@@QAE?AV?$shared_ptr@VGameSelectScene@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Game::init(char const *,int,int,bool)" (?init@Game@@QAEXPBDHH_N@Z)
Game.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::shared_ptr<class MainMenuScene> __thiscall SceneManager::ChangeScene<class MainMenuScene>(void)" (??$ChangeScene@VMainMenuScene@@@SceneManager@@QAE?AV?$shared_ptr@VMainMenuScene@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Game::init(char const *,int,int,bool)" (?init@Game@@QAEXPBDHH_N@Z)
```

In my game.h I have:

```
#pragma once

class SceneManager; 

using namespace std;

class Game {
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void init(const char* title, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);
    void handleEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    void clean();

    bool isRunning() { return running; }

    static SDL_Renderer * renderer; 
    static SceneManager * sceneManager; 
};
```

The errors are happening in my game.cpp file in the init() method and my game.cpp looks like:

```
#include "Game.h"

#include "SceneManager.h"

#include "GameSelectScene.h"
#include "MainMenuScene.h" 

SceneManager * Game::sceneManager = new SceneManager();

Game::Game() {}
Game::~Game() {}

void Game::init(const char* title, int width, int height, bool fullscreen) {
    // I do some stuff up here

    // Here is where I think errors are happening.
    sceneManager->AddScene<MainMenuScene>();
    sceneManager->AddScene<GameSelectScene>();

    sceneManager->ChangeScene<MainMenuScene>();
}
```

My GameSelectScene.h and MainMenuScene.h are both subclasses of my Scene.h
and my SceneManager is where the AddScene and ChangeScene methods are defined

My SceneManager.h:
    #pragma once

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Scene.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>

using namespace std;

class SceneManager {
public:
    SceneManager();
    ~SceneManager();

    void init();
    void update();
    void render();

    template <typename T> std::shared_ptr<T> ChangeScene();
    template <typename T> std::shared_ptr<T> AddScene();

private:
    std::map<type_index, std::shared_ptr<Scene>> scenes;
    std::shared_ptr<Scene> currentScene;
};
```

SceneManager.cpp:

```
#include "SceneManager.h"

SceneManager::SceneManager() {}
SceneManager::~SceneManager() {}

// I define the init() update() and render()

template <typename T> std::shared_ptr<T> SceneManager::ChangeScene() {
    type_index index(typeid(T));
    currentScene = scenes[index];
    return static_pointer_cast<T>(scenes[index]);
}

template <typename T> std::shared_ptr<T> SceneManager::AddScene() {
    T scene = new T();    
    scenes[std::type_index(typeid(*scene))] = scene;
    return scene;
}
```

If I remove my AddScene and ChangeScene method calls in the game.cpp file everything compiles correctly and the update, init and render methods defined in the SceneManager run perfectly. I have been researching this issue and walked through all the problems described in [MSDN LNK2019 Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(LNK2019)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template functions must be defined in header files, not cpp.

[Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problems. I was focused on the #includes or something. However, because I am fairly new to C++ I am trying to figure out what would be best with my map<type_index, shared_ptr<Component>>. I want to call the methods of the object in the shared pointer which is a subclass of the component class. I have looked at a lot of answers and want to make sure I am going about it correctly. Would it be best to do and ptr.get() and then somehow cast it to the subtype so I can call specific methods.. or is there a way I could initialize my map as map<type_index, shared_ptr<T>>

Comment: @TaylorRiccetti Can you ask a separate question about it? It's hard for me to understand the idea.